# why get_the_post_thumbnail( the_ID()) echos extra post id

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, post-thumbnails, archives

I have the following snippet which adds post thumbnails to products on archive page if matches a given product category, which will output the image but echos the the post id as well. How do I suppress to not show post id?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', function () {
    if(is_product_category('t-shirts')) {
        $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( the_ID());
        if(is_string($thumb) ) {
            echo '<div class="imagewrapper">' . $thumb;
        }
    }

}, 9 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', function () {
    if(is_product_category('t-shirts')) {
        $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( the_ID());
        if(is_string($thumb) ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}, 11 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe because:

> **the_ID()** :   Display the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.

and

> **get_the_ID()** : Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress
>   Loop.

So `the_ID()` *displays* the post ID.
Try to use `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Yep thanks a lot! I just took a look on the 2 methods ``/**
 * Display the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 */
function the_ID() {
 echo get_the_ID();
}

/**
 * Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @return int|false The ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop. False if $post is not set.
 */
function get_the_ID() {
 $post = get_post();
 return ! empty( $post ) ? $post->ID : false;
}
``